# Assign "this" to a reference variable in Java

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to used recursive method to complete the addLast method in a singly linked list, however, the code gives me a wrong output of list.size() = 2 and list.getFirst() = 5. The reason should be due to the line

```
SLList p=this;
```

It seems changing p reference changes "this" reference as well, which is not so logic to me. Could anyone give some details about this? Thx

```
public class SLList {
public class IntNode {
    public int item;
    public IntNode next;
    public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
        item = i;
        next = n;
    }
}

private IntNode first;

public SLList(int x) {
    first = new IntNode(x, null);
}

/** Adds an item to the front of the list. */
public void addFirst(int x) {
    first = new IntNode(x, first);
}

/** Retrieves the front item from the list. */
public int getFirst() {
    return first.item;
}

/** Adds an item to the end of the list. */
public void addLast(int x) {

    SLList p = this;
    if (p.first. next == null) {
        p.first.next = new IntNode (x, null);
    }

    else {
        p.first = p.first.next;
        p.addLast(x);
    }

}

/** Returns the number of items in the list using recursion. */
public int size() {
    /* Your Code Here! */
    SLList p = this;
    if (p.first == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (p.first.next == null){
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        p.first = p.first.next;
        return 1 + p.size();
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    SLList list=new SLList (5);
    list.addFirst(10);
    list.addFirst(15);
    list.addLast(17);
    System.out.println(list.getFirst());
    System.out.println(list.size());

}

}
```

Comment: `SLList p=this;` doesn't make a new object. You just have two references to the same `SLList`.

Comment: *Nothing* can change the value of `this`.

Comment: For object types, assignment is just a reference copy. The language doesn't implicitly copy objects everywhere like C++.

Comment: Yes, I understand, no new reference has been made. However, in the addLast method, every time p.first = p.first.next; should only change p's pointer, but the code output looks like "this" pointer is changing as well

Comment: `p` and `this` refer to the same object. Of course it's getting updated when you update it, via either reference.

Comment: @rifle123 that is how reference work. After the assignment, `p` and `this` refer to the same object. However, as the answer below says, you have other problems. `size()` should not have any side effects. It should not modify the list in any way.

Comment: NB This is exactly what should happen. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is nothing to do with the assignment of `this`.  Nothing can change `this`.  Period.

(But things can change the state of the object that `this` refers to.)

The real problem is in your implementation of the `size` method.  Your `size` method is causing the list to change.  It shouldn't.  In your case, the change causes:

- the `size()` method to return the wrong value
- subsequent `getFirst()` calls to return the wrong value.

I won't say exactly where the bug, but you should be able to spot it yourself *by a process of elimination*.  (Or if that fails, use a debugger and try to observe where the list is changing.)

Comment: Thank you. I noticed this problem now. In some cases, we use a placeholder refer to the object and iterate, such as IntNode p=first, and then iterate p=p.next without changing the list. I'm confused with this IntNode p=first; and SSList p=first; it looks like both are not creating new objects, but the latter would change the list during iteration. Could you give some details on this? Thx

Answer (score 1):

There are bigger problems with your algorithms than you think. `size()` is incorrect. You can fix this if you realize that you need to count the number of `IntNode` objects in the list. Similarly all other methods need to manipulate `IntNode` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
SLList p = this;
```

p reference to the same SLList object. if you make any changes to 'p' then it will also happened to 'this',  becuase of reference type (not value type).

Here in the statement

```
p.first = p.first.next;
```

the reference to the first is changed when you call 'addLast' method. You loss the reference to the first item.

If you remove the line

```
list.addLast(17);
```

in main method you will see the correct answer. The problem is with this method.

Change the method as follow and add the new method below.

```
/** Adds an item to the end of the list. */
public void addLast(int x) {
    addLast(x, this.first);
}

private void addLast(int x, IntNode node){
    if(node.next == null){
        node.next = new IntNode (x, null);
    }else {
        node = node.next;
        addLast(x, node);
    }
}
```

Then you will not lose the reference to first item and now it works fine,

Comment: Please don't do this.  If you point out where someone's bugs are in a homework question, you are actually **depriving** them of the **important** learning experience of finding them for themselves.  The right thing to do is to give them some hints so that they can find the problems themselves.

Comment: I'm really so sorry about this. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: OK - advice for a newbie: consider the context of a question when answering.  Ask yourself: will my answer actually (really) help the person most likely to read it?

Comment: Thank you all. @Stephen C.  In the question, I just want to try if recursive can be implemented in one single function. The one confused me is my intention is to use "SSList p=this" to make p as a place holder. Just as in addLast(), we could also use iteration method                                     
           IntNode p=first;         
           while (p.next != null) {
             p = p.next;         }
         p.next = new IntNode (x, null);}
 Compare the two codes "IntNode p=first" and "SSList p =this", both are copy by reference, but different performance, why?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your implementation is addLast and size method are changing the value of field variable first.

It don't matter whether you assign`this` to some variable or use directly.
Because assigning `this` to some variable does not create new `this` object but assign's reference to that variable.

So you should first copy value of `first` field variable to some local variable then iterate on it.In this way your `first` will not change.

Hint: Don't change the first variable reference.
Your `addLast()` and `size()` changes value of `first` which is wrong.
Problem is in this line.
    p.first = p.first.next;